# Ocr could not convert some characters properly in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ocr

I am trying to get text from element which are inside canvas, I am trying to capture canvas portion as image and then extracting text from image using OCR library. But I am facing issue as some of characters are not getting converted in exact text.

I am using Selenium webdriver, Java and Maven.

**Code to extract text from image:**

```
    Ocr.setUp();
    Ocr ocr = new Ocr(); // create a new OCR engine
    ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST); // English

    textFromImage = ocr.recognize(new File[]{new File("E:\\Device.png")},
            Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_TEXT, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
    System.out.println(textFromImage);
    ocr.stopEngine();
```

Currently I am trying to get text which is in google search text box from below image :

[image]

I am expecting output as get text : `What is swift in iOS`
But OCR returns text : `Whatls swlflln IOS` as per following screenshot:

[image]

Some how OCR could not covert some characters same as what in image. Is there any other solution for this?